How do I make the Long Text format (from Access database) display actual text on my DBGrid component in Delphi?
I want to be able to see what the field contains in a TDBGrid component in Delphi, but it just shows (WIDEMEMO) instead. I'm too scared that I'm going to break something if I reformat the field to be short text in Access.
I want to make a button that shows the text in a ShowMessage() dialogue, but it's not very user friendly.

Adding and describing a desire is not a viable question.  Attempt to rephrase this as a code related question perhaps with what you tried and the one challenge that presents you

Check this.
